# Column names in each table must be unique exception

Tags: c#, sql

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Delivery' in table 'Sales' is specified more than once.

How can I solve this? I get a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`.

```
class DataAccess
{
    string ConnectionString;

    public DataAccess()
    {
        ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CafeteriaDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }        



    public bool RecordASale(ArrayList ProductsList, DateTime SaleTime, int SalesmanID, decimal CashGiven, decimal TotalBill, decimal CashReturn, string Delivery)
    {
        int SaleID = ReturnSaleID();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("alter table [Sales] add [Delivery] varchar default 5 NOT NULL"))
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            /*Start a local transaction*/
            SqlTransaction sqlTran = connection.BeginTransaction();

            /*Enlist a command in the current transaction*/
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.Transaction = sqlTran;

            try
            {
                // Execute separate commands.
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleTime", SaleTime);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesmanID", SalesmanID);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CashGiven", CashGiven);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalBill", TotalBill);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CashReturn", CashReturn);
                /*command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Delivery", Delivery);*/

                command.CommandText =
                   "Insert into Sales (SaleTime, SalesmanID, CashGiven, TotalBill, CashReturn, Delivery) values (@SaleTime, @SalesmanID, @CashGiven, @TotalBill, @CashReturn, @Delivery)";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                foreach (Details ProductDetail in ProductsList)
                {
                    //// Execute separate commands.
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", ProductDetail.Name);
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductPrice", ProductDetail.Price);
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductQuantity", ProductDetail.Quantity);
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductTotal", ProductDetail.Total);
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleID", SaleID);

                    command.CommandText =
                       "Insert into SaleItems (ProductName, ProductPrice, ProductQuantity, ProductTotal, SaleID) values ('" + ProductDetail.Name + "', '" + ProductDetail.Price + "', '" + ProductDetail.Quantity + "', '" + ProductDetail.Total + "', '" + SaleID + "')";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                // Commit the transaction.
                sqlTran.Commit();

                //connection.Close();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                throw ee;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Give another name to the column, as the error is clearly states that you can't have two columns with same name in a table.

Comment: below the code connection.Open(); you are using a sql comand  new SqlCommand("alter table [Sales] add [Delivery] varchar default 5 NOT NULL")), i think it must be it the problem, because probably the column already exists and when u open a con you try to add the column again

Comment: ok, thank you but what do you propose?? i refactor the column name but thrown this exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint ..........DEBUG\CAFETERIADB.MDF", table "dbo.Sales", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if your column exists before adding it to the datatable you should change your code in this way

```
 string sql = @"if NOT exists(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                    WHERE Column_Name = 'Delivery' AND Table_Name = 'Sales')  
                    ALTER TABLE Sales ADD Delivery VARCHAR DEFAULT 5 NOT NULL";
 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql))
 {
      command.Connection = connection;
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

In this way the operation to add the column Delivery to he table Sales will be executed only if the query on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS doesn't return a value

I have also noticed now that you are building your INSERT command concatenating strings together. This is a well know security problem that you can learn about searching how one can use it for Sql Injection

Also, if the SalesID column is an Identity column, you should not try to pass a value for it in the sql query